# Entering numbers from the numpad using pynput (or any other library)

Tags: python, keyboard, pynput

I am trying to enter Alt-codes of symbols using the pynput library (Imitation of pressing "Alt" and entering code on the numpad)

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyb = Controller()

def alt_codes(start, finish):  
    for i in range(start, finish + 1):
        keyb.press(Key.alt)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        for j in str(i):
            keyb.press(j)
            time.sleep(0.01)
            keyb.release(j)
            time.sleep(0.01)
        keyb.release(Key.alt)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        keyb.press(Key.space)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        keyb.release(Key.space)
```

But if I just try to simulate pressing the numbers 0 to 9, it doesn't work, because it simulates pressing the keys that are above the letters, and to enter the Alt code, you need to simulate the numbers from the Numpad.
How can I simulate pressing numbers on a numpad?
UPD: You can use any other library if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For specifically targeting the Numpad keys you can use their Virtual-Key Codes

[image: The Virtual Codes for 0-9 Numpad keys]

You can find the whole list here https://cherrytree.at/misc/vk.htm

Now for the Code to Use the Virtual Key Codes

```
keyb.press(key=KeyCode.from_vk(96)) #Number tells which numpad key to press, 96 means 0
```

instead of

```
keyb.press(j)
```

You can change the start to finish instead of `0 to 9` to
`96 to 105`. In this way, you can press the specific key subsequently
Or you can define a mapping for it like this:

```
get_keycode = {
    0: 96,
    1: 97,
    2: 98,
    3: 99,
    4: 100,
    5: 101,
    6: 102,
    7: 103,
    8: 104,
    9: 105
}
```

Now your final code would be (I tried writing Euro Sign ALT-Code is 0128):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller, KeyCode
import time

keyb = Controller()
    
get_keycode = {
    0: 96,
    1: 97,
    2: 98,
    3: 99,
    4: 100,
    5: 101,
    6: 102,
    7: 103,
    8: 104,
    9: 105
}

def get_key(key):
    return KeyCode.from_vk(get_keycode[int(key)])
    
euro_sign = "0128"
keyb.press(Key.alt)
time.sleep(0.01)
for j in euro_sign:
    keyb.press(get_key(j))
    time.sleep(0.01)
    keyb.release(get_key(j))
    time.sleep(0.01)
keyb.release(Key.alt)
time.sleep(0.01)
keyb.press(Key.space)
time.sleep(0.01)
keyb.release(Key.space)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, with AutoHotkey (or [Python's `ahk` library](https://github.com/spyoungtech/ahk)) you can just input the characters directly. No need to think about the numpad or altcodes (although doing that is possible, too).

```
pip install "ahk[binary]"
```

```py
from ahk import AHK

ahk = AHK()

ahk.type('hello special keys: §') # § is keycode 0167
```

You can send just about whatever you want as a normal string and it'll work as long as the program receiving the input accepts the special characters.

```py
ahk.type("this should work™ -- hello  from Python®")
```

Or using the clipboard can be a similarly convenient way to do this:

```py
text = 'this should work™ -- hello  from Python®'
ahk.set_clipboard(text)
# and paste yourself or... 
ahk.send_input('^v') # send CTRL + v
```

Or the 'manual' way with [numpad keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/KeyList.htm#numpad):

```py
ahk.send('{LALT down}')
for num in '0167':
    keyname = f'{{Numpad{num}}}'
    ahk.send(keyname)
ahk.send('{LALT up}')
```

---

<sup>Full disclosure, I author the `ahk` library</sup>